# The use of need_resched flag and schedule() routine within Linux kernel [2.4]

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, redhat, rhel

As per my understanding when the kernel finds out that the current running process should be striped of the CPU, it enables the need_resched flag.
The flag is then checked before returning to user space, and if the flag enabled the kernel initiates call for schedule().
However I have noticed that within sys_sched_yield() routine we don't use the need_resched flag but explicitly call the schedule() routine.
Why?

Comment: `sys_sched_yield` is intended for rescheduling(it is syscall actually). Because it is called from user space, kernel can immediately perform scheduling instead of setting `need_resched`  flag.

Comment: I know that sys_sched_yield() is a system call implementation.
need_resched can't be accessed from user mode so your second sentence doesn't really have a meaning.

Comment: You say that `need_resched can't be accessed from user mode`, but  expect `sys_sched_yield` to check `need_resched` flag. Why?

Comment: sys_sched_yield is a method within sched.c it runs in kernel mode.
Dont confuse system call wrapper functions and kernel code.

Comment: sys_sched_yield is a method within sched.c, it runs in kernel mode **and** it implements system call `sched_yield`. There is no confusion here. Every system call is implemented as kernel code.

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101760&seqNum=3), `need_resched` flag is used for mark process *externally*: within interrupt by `scheduler_tick()` or when process is awoken by other process with `try_to_wake_up()`. Flag is needed, because the process itself may be not ready for rescheduling, so rescheduling is deffered until *safe quiescent state*.

If the process *itself* requests rescheduling, via `schedule()` call in kernel space, or via `sched_yield()` system call in user space, kernel performs request immediately. It is assumed that the process knows what it does. In the last case(when `sched_yield()` is called in user space), kernel knows that it is always safe to rescheduling while process in the user space.